# Get data from txt to different lists in python (colab)

Tags: python, text, google-colaboratory

I want to get data from txt files into different variables using loop
for example

```
txt1 = 1,1,1,1,1
txt2 = 2,2,2,2,2
txt3 = 3,3,3,3,3


list1 => txt1
list2 => txt2
list3 => txt3
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your text files stored in text_files directory, you can do the following

```
import os

my_data = []
for file in os.listdir("text_files"):
    with open(os.path.join("text_files",file)) as file_in:
        for line in file_in:
            my_data.append(line)
```

This will initialize an empty list then it will loop through the files in the directory, then append each line inside the list.